# LoopBack: How to define middleware intercepting REST API calls ONLY?

Tags: middleware, loopbackjs, strongloop

If I register middleware in *server/middleware.json*, this middleware is executed for each request, regardless of its kind. But for authorization checks, I need execution **only** for calls of *API paths*. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The below answer aside, are you not using the built-in auth mechanism for loopback for some reason? The user model has auth out of the box, so to speak. See `server/boot/authentication.js`.

Comment: It is an additional kind of authorization. Not user-based, but preshared-secret-based. I would like to check in the middleware, if the secret is present in the form of a database query filter option. Anyway: If there is some built-in method to achieve this, I would definitely prefer the built-in way.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file inside `server/boot`, like this example I made to preview email templates in a browser for development. You just add an express route as you would inside an express app:

```
// from the loopback custom express route docs:
//
// module.exports = function(app) {
//   var router = app.loopback.Router();
//   router.get('/ping', function(req, res) {
//     res.send('pong');
//   });
//   app.use(router);
// }
var fs                 = require('fs');
var Mustache           = require('mustache');
var path               = require('path');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get('/emails/:template', function(req, res) {

    var data = {
      // data for template render
    };

    var template = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../client/views/emails/' + req.params.template), 'utf-8');
    var html = Mustache.render(template, data);

    res.send(html);

  });

}
```

`http://localhost:3000/ping` should output "pong".

See http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Add+a+custom+Express+route

So, if you need something to fire on all API events, instead of an explicit path as above you could try:

```
app.all('/api/*', requireAuthentication);
```

to match on the /api prefix to run that middleware.

See: http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.all

Comment: I tried to add such a wildcard route, but all pre-existing routes by-pass my wildcard route.